# Owl slider only mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, slider

I use plugin http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/.
I want to create slider only on mobile, this is my code:

```
$(".product_list").owlCarousel({
    itemsTablet: [480, 1],
    navigation: true
});
```

This create owl on 480px, but when i resize window to bigger i see owl dom elements. I want to regenerate dom code after change to bigger resolution and remove owl from html DOM.
How to regenerate or remove this code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best , if you hide owlcarousel and only show on specific resolution:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if (window.innerWidth > 480)
     {
       $(".product_list").hide();
     }
   else
    {
      $(".product_list").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, but on desktop view i have a grid and a mobile i have slider